# $\forall x \in (0, 1], \exists! n\in\mathbb{N} \text{ such that} \frac{1}{2^n}<x\leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, algorithms

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

\begin{equation}
(0,1] = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2^n}, \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right]
\end{equation}

In order to prove the above statement, I have to prove that

\begin{equation}
\forall x \in (0, 1], \exists! n\in\mathbb{N} \text{ such that} \frac{1}{2^n}<x\leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}.
\end{equation}

The following is the proof that I came up with, and I'd like to know if the proof is valid.

First, due to the Archimedean property of real numbers, for all $x\in(0,1]$ there exists a natural number $m$ such that $x>\frac{1}{2^m}$.

Suppose we found such $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, define the following algorithm.

1. if $x\leq\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}$, let $n=m$ and terminate.
2. if $x > \frac{1}{2^{m-1}}$, $m \gets m-1$ and return to 1.

I have not formally learned how to prove a statement by providing an algorithm, but I thought that I have to show that **(1) the algorithm terminates** **(2) the result is as desired**.

**(1)** To show that the algorithm terminates, I argued that if the algorithm doesn't terminate for $m\geq 2$, it must terminate for $m=1$ because $x\leq 1= \frac{1}{2^{1-1}}$.

**(2)** Next, the result $n$ is what we desired because

2.a) $n\in\mathbb{N}$ because we start with a natural number $m$, and during each step $m$ decreases by 1 (if it does), and it is guaranteed to be $m\geq 1$.

2.b) First, $x\leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ because of how we defined sequence 1. Next, $x>\frac{1}{2^n}$ because of how we defined sequence 2 (i.e. we reduce $m$ by 1 only if $x>\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}$.)

Therefore, the result $n$ is a natural number such that $\frac{1}{2^n}<x\leq\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$.

To sum up, my question is: Is this the right way to prove something by providing an algorithm? **To be specific, is there anything other than (1) or (2) to verify, and is the way I phrased the proof valid?** I'm confused because as opposed to proof by contradiction or induction where you have a specific goal, I feel like the format of the proof of this kind is less definitive.

Comment: You don't need to show $n$ is unique, just that it exists (even though it is unique). You can simplify this train of thought using the fact that every non-empty set of natural numbers has a smallest element.

Comment: Let $I_n = \left(\frac{1}{2^n}, \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right]$ and show that if $n \neq m$ then $I_n, I_m$ are disjoint. This establishes uniqueness. Show that $\cup_{n=1}^m I_n =  \left(\frac{1}{2^m}, 1\right]$. This establishes existence.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for your comment! I didn't know that when I construct an infinite union of sets I have to establish its existence. Can you elaborate on why this is needed and how to do this? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @JaebeomYim I did not mean the existence of the infinite union, I meant that for any $x \in (01,]$ there exists some $m$ such that $ x\in \cup_{n=1}^m I_n$.

Comment: @copper.hat Okay I see, thank you for clarifying.